# Python Selenium webscraping mutiple pages(increment page number in url)

Tags: xpath, web

I have little to none programming experience and I just started learning Python two weeks ago it was a pain running under windows (e.g. environment variable etc  something I didn't really know what it is until two weeks ago).

I am using seleniumto  try to web scrape information.
basically the url(mainly jscript) pages changes incrementally:
e.g.

```
http://sssss.proxy.sssss/sample#/detail/0/1
http://sssss.proxy.sssss/sample#/detail/0/2
http://sssss.proxy.sssss/sample#/detail/1/1
http://sssss.proxy.sssss/sample#/detail/1/2
http://sssss.proxy.sssss/sample#/detail/2/1
http://sssss.proxy.sssss/sample#/detail/2/2
http://sssss.proxy.sssss/sample#/detail/50/1
http://sssss.proxy.sssss/sample#/detail/50/2
```

I want to pragmatically and systemically webscrape specific content(find by xpath) under each page and its subpage. However, I don't know how loop works (e.g. for i to xxx) in this case because every url has to be "get" by browser web driver. (does it mean the loop will initiate the browser to open every single page or will it happen within python shell like in request package)

There are method for scraping content for url that is fixed. But in my case the url does changes so I assume it can be done differently.

Please enlighten me
With thanks,
Iverson

Comment: Take a look at these links https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html ,        http://www.python-course.eu/python3_for_loop.php etc, take a look at range method and show some code you tried to solve the problem

Comment: @IV_Z is your python running smoothly now? I use Anaconda (python), selenium and scrapy. They were very easy to install and I had no contact with environment variables.

Comment: @Roshan Jossey  hum how would loop work with the web driver???will it open everypage ??

Comment: @IV_Z Yes you can open every page. driver.get()

Comment: @Roshan Jossey, is it possible to not open every page via the driver but still be able to get the source code for scraping??

Comment: I'm not sure of that.

Comment: Hey guys, need more help here.
I now able to find the url and save it to a variable within a session(e.g. the below)

http://xxxx.proxy.xxxxx./ssssss#/detail/1/4'

but how can I define loop to increment "/detail/1" (e.g./detail/1. detail/2.....) and scrap the content from there??

With thanks,
Iverson